# Python split list values based on condition

Tags: python, regex

Given a python list split values based on certain criteria:

```
    list = ['(( value(name) = literal(luke) or value(like) = literal(music) ) 
     and (value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid))',
    '(( value(sam) = literal(abc) or value(like) = literal(music) ) and 
     (value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid))']
```

Now list[0] would be

```
  (( value(name) = literal(luke) or value(like) = literal(music) ) 
     and (value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid))
```

I want to split such that upon iterating it would give me:

```
#expected output
value(sam) = literal(abc)
value(like) = literal(music)
```

That too if it starts with value and literal. At first I thought of splitting with and ,or but it won't work as sometimes there could be missing and ,or.

I tried :

```
for i in list:
i.split()
print(i)
#output ['((', 'value(abc)', '=', 'literal(12)', 'or' ....
```

I am open to suggestions based on regex also. But I have little idea about it I prefer not to include it

Comment: You might want to look into parsing, e.g. `PEG` here. Don't you mess with regular expressions. Additionally, where do these strings come from? Maybe just go upriver.

Comment: I had a xml from which I made an AST from it to get this desired string . But at the end I wan't given list as the output just with few values replaced like I mentioned.

Comment: @Jan can you help me with PEG. I am trying to use [parsimonious](https://github.com/erikrose/parsimonious) here

Comment: Added an example, see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**So to avoid so much clutter, I'm going to explain the solution in this comment. I hope that's okay.**

**Given your comment above which I couldn't quite understand, is this what you want? I changed the list to add in the other values you mentioned:**

```
>>> import re
>>> list = ['''(( value(name) = literal(luke) or value(like) = literal(music) ) 
and (value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid))''',
'''(( value(sam) = literal(abc) or value(like) = literal(music) ) and 
(value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid))''',
'''(value(PICK_SKU1) = propval(._sku)''', '''propval(._amEntitled) > literal(0))''']


>>> found_list = []
>>> for item in list:
        for element in re.findall('([\w\.]+(?:\()[\w\.]+(?:\))[\s=<>(?:in)]+[\w\.]+(?:\()[\w\.]+(?:\)))', item):
            found_list.append(element)

>>> found_list
['value(name) = literal(luke)', 'value(like) = literal(music)', 'value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid)', 'value(sam) = literal(abc)', 'value(like) = literal(music)', 'value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid)', 'value(PICK_SKU1) = propval(._sku)', 'propval(._amEntitled) > literal(0)']
```

**Explanation:**

- Pre-Note - I changed `[a-zA-Z0-9\._]+` to `[\w\.]+` because they mean essentially the same thing but one is more concise. I explain what characters are covered by those queries in the next step
- With `([\w\.]+`, noting that it is "unclosed" meaning I am priming the regex to capture everything in the following query, I am telling it to begin by capturing all characters that are in the range `a-z`, `A-Z`, and `_`, and an escaped period (`.`)
- With `(?:\()` I am saying the captured query should contain an escaped "opening" parenthesis (`(`)
- With `[\w\.]+(?:\))` I'm saying follow that parenthesie again with the word characters outlined in the second step, but this time through `(?:\))` I'm saying follow them with an escaped "closing" parenthesis (`)`)
- This `[\s=<>(?:in)]+` is kind of reckless but for the sake of readability and assuming that your strings will remain relatively consistent this says, that the "closing parenthesis" should be followed by `"whitespace"`, a `=`, a `<`, a `>`, or the word `in`, in any order however many times they all occur consistently. It is reckless because it will also match things like `<<  <`, `= in > =`, etc. To make it more specific could easily result in a loss of captures though
- With `[\w\.]+(?:\()[\w\.]+(?:\))` I'm saying once again, find the word characters from step 1, followed by an "opening parenthesis," followed again by the word characters, followed by a "closing parenthesis"
- With the `)` I am closing the "unclosed" capture group (remember the first capture group above started as "unclosed"), to tell the regex engine to capture the entire query I have outlined

**Hope this helps**

Comment: LOL. I'm just hoping newcomers can understand it too. Glad it helped, man.

Answer (score 1):

**@Duck_dragon**

Your strings in your list in the opening post were formatted in such a way that they cause a syntax error in Python. In the example I give below, I edited it to use `'''`

```
>>> import re
>>> list = ['''(( value(name) = literal(luke) or value(like) = literal(music) ) 
 and (value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid))''',
'''(( value(sam) = literal(abc) or value(like) = literal(music) ) and 
 (value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid))''']


#Simple findall without setting it equal to a variable so it returns a list of separate strings but which you can't use
#You can also use the *MORE SIMPLE* but less flexible regex:  '([a-zA-Z]+\([a-zA-Z]+\)[\s=]+[a-zA-Z]+\([a-zA-Z]+\))'
>>> for item in list:
        re.findall('([a-zA-Z]+(?:\()[a-zA-Z]+(?:\))[\s=]+[a-zA-Z]+(?:\()[a-zA-Z]+(?:\)))', item)    

    ['value(name) = literal(luke)', 'value(like) = literal(music)']
    ['value(sam) = literal(abc)', 'value(like) = literal(music)']
```

.

To take this a step further and give you an array you can work with:

```
>>> import re
>>> list = ['''(( value(name) = literal(luke) or value(like) = literal(music) ) 
 and (value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid))''',
'''(( value(sam) = literal(abc) or value(like) = literal(music) ) and 
 (value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid))''']


#Declaring blank array found_list which you can use to call the individual items
>>> found_list = []
>>> for item in list:
        for element in re.findall('([a-zA-Z]+(?:\()[a-zA-Z]+(?:\))[\s=]+[a-zA-Z]+(?:\()[a-zA-Z]+(?:\)))', item):
            found_list.append(element)


>>> found_list
['value(name) = literal(luke)', 'value(like) = literal(music)', 'value(sam) = literal(abc)', 'value(like) = literal(music)']
```

.

**Given your comment below which I couldn't quite understand, is this what you want? I changed the list to add in the other values you mentioned:**

```
>>> import re
>>> list = ['''(( value(name) = literal(luke) or value(like) = literal(music) ) 
and (value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid))''',
'''(( value(sam) = literal(abc) or value(like) = literal(music) ) and 
(value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid))''',
'''(value(PICK_SKU1) = propval(._sku)''', '''propval(._amEntitled) > literal(0))''']


>>> found_list = []
>>> for item in list:
        for element in re.findall('([\w\.]+(?:\()[\w\.]+(?:\))[\s=<>(?:in)]+[\w\.]+(?:\()[\w\.]+(?:\)))', item):
            found_list.append(element)

>>> found_list
['value(name) = literal(luke)', 'value(like) = literal(music)', 'value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid)', 'value(sam) = literal(abc)', 'value(like) = literal(music)', 'value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid)', 'value(PICK_SKU1) = propval(._sku)', 'propval(._amEntitled) > literal(0)']
```

.

**Edit: Or is this what you want?**

```
>>> import re
>>> list = ['''(( value(name) = literal(luke) or value(like) = literal(music) ) 
 and (value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid))''',
'''(( value(sam) = literal(abc) or value(like) = literal(music) ) and 
 (value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid))''']


#Declaring blank array found_list which you can use to call the individual items
>>> found_list = []
>>> for item in list:
        for element in re.findall('([a-zA-Z]+(?:\()[a-zA-Z]+(?:\))[\s=<>(?:in)]+[a-zA-Z]+(?:\()[a-zA-Z]+(?:\)))', item):
            found_list.append(element)


>>> found_list
['value(name) = literal(luke)', 'value(like) = literal(music)', 'value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid)', 'value(sam) = literal(abc)', 'value(like) = literal(music)', 'value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid)']
```

Let me know if you need an explanation.

.

**@Fyodor Kutsepin**

In your example take out `your_list_` and replace it with OP's `list` to avoid confusion. Secondly, your `for loop` lacks a `:` producing syntax errors

Comment: Thanks @FailSafe. Can you help me explain the regex. In this case it is working fine and ignoring this `(value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid))` but in my original list there are values such as `(value(PICK_SKU1) = propval(._sku),'`,`propval(._amEntitled) > literal(0))'` etc. but I only intend to find literal and value. maybe @Jan suggestion of using PEG would be helpful if regex can't solve this. But I appreciate whatever you did.

Comment: okay. there are so many cases that we need to put many conditions in regex if thats how it works. can you make changes to your regex to include `<>=in` operators. After that I will figure out what to do with it.

Comment: I made an edit. I'm not sure what exactly you need, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thats exactly what I intend to find. Can you explain it on a higher level.

Comment: I changed it again, but I will explain in a moment. It's gonna take me a bit of time to get the explanation together.

Comment: ok thanks. But do explain me the difference between your previous and latest. As previous one was also working

Comment: Yep, I will. It should be posted in about 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest you to avoid of naming your variables like build-in functions.
Second, you don't need a regex if you want to get the mentioned output.

for example:

```
first, rest = your_list_[1].split(') and'):
for item in first[2:].split('or')
    print(item)
```

Comment: You're missing a `:` after the `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

Not saying you should but you definately could use a `PEG` parser here:

```
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar
from parsimonious.nodes import NodeVisitor

data = ['(( value(name) = literal(luke) or value(like) = literal(music) ) and (value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid))',
        '(( value(sam) = literal(abc) or value(like) = literal(music) ) and (value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid))']

grammar = Grammar(
    r"""
    expr        = term (operator term)*
    term        = lpar* factor (operator needle)* rpar*
    factor      = needle operator needle

    needle      = word lpar word rpar

    operator    = ws? ("=" / "or" / "and" / "in") ws?
    word        = ~"\w+"

    lpar        = "(" ws?
    rpar        = ws? ")"
    ws          = ~r"\s*"
    """
)

class HorribleStuff(NodeVisitor):
    def generic_visit(self, node, visited_children):
        return node.text or visited_children

    def visit_factor(self, node, children):
        output, equal = [], False

        for child in node.children:
            if (child.expr.name == 'needle'):
                output.append(child.text)
            elif (child.expr.name == 'operator' and child.text.strip() == '='):
                equal = True

        if equal:
            print(output)

for d in data:
    tree = grammar.parse(d)
    hs = HorribleStuff()
    hs.visit(tree)
```

This yields

```
['value(name)', 'literal(luke)']
['value(sam)', 'literal(abc)']
```